# How to bind variables to INPUT dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have an object in the controller which value I am getting from http GET request:

```
$scope.myObj = {

      id1: "1",
      id2: "5",
      id3: "",
      id4: ""
    };
```

It can have any number of fields (`id...`) with any values. But if `id-k` is not empty all `id-n` where `n < k` is not empty too.

I need to bind to `INPUT` last not empty field of the object.  What is best way to do it?

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9vzVxNtgDd3aAeWzKtml?p=preview)

**Update:**  This object is a position in the classificator.
In my example `ID` of position is `1.5`. I need to allow edit only last position in the classification. The user can change `5` to `6`, `7` or anything else, but it can not change `1` segment

If the object will be

```
$scope.myObj = {

          id1: "2",
          id2: "5",
          id3: "4",
          id4: "8"
        };
```

The classification is `2.5.4.8` and user must be able edit only last segment - `8`.

Comment: I came up with this solution. [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ql6sOmOvZINk8FFjv2rH?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```
...
$scope.myObj = {
  id1: "1",
  id2: "5",
  id3: "6",
  id4: ""
};

$scope.segments = Object.keys($scope.myObj)
  .filter(function(key) {
    return $scope.myObj[key];
  })
  .sort(function(a, b){
    return Number(a.replace('id', '')) - Number(b.replace('id', ''));
  });
 ...
```

**HTML**

```
<span ng-repeat="segment in segments">
   <span ng-if="!$last">{{ myObj[segment] }}</span>
   <input ng-if="$last" ng-model="myObj[segment]">
</span>

<p>{{ myObj }}</p>
```

---

Plnkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/8C9lLLdCvvzFinaOXqtd?p=preview

---

**Original Answer**

You can calculate the last non blank id in the controller and set it to a scope variable. Something like

```
$scope.myLast = $scope.myObj['id' + Object.keys($scope.myObj).reduce(function(a, key){
  if ($scope.myObj[key]) {
    var idNum = Number(key.replace('id', ''));
    a = Math.max(a, idNum)
  }
  return a;
}, -Infinity)];
```

Note - you can't rely on the order of keys, so you can't actually assume that the last key is the biggest one.

---

Plnkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/apy8qZNJNK4Q23J5Ja4N?p=preview

Comment: But when I will change `myLast` in the `INPUT` the `myObj.id2` will remain the same.  I changed your code to show this https://plnkr.co/edit/OPU5SL78Q4Bd4vUHqvCl?p=preview

Comment: Um.. I seem to have misunderstood the question the. Sorry! Does https://plnkr.co/edit/KHEOV6QnDzfPlvvxBMiZ?p=preview or https://plnkr.co/edit/7eWErMMfr2mx70lZBCfI?p=preview seem closer to what you are looking for? I didn't quite get why we'd change the last available key. I thought the updates would be driven by the values.

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know how to explain this better, but I just want to edit last not empty field of MY object. All your examples bind the new variable, but not mine.  I can use your first example https://plnkr.co/edit/OPU5SL78Q4Bd4vUHqvCl?p=preview and add `$watch` to bind two variables - your new `myLast` and `myObj`, but I am looking for better solution.

Comment: I have updated my question to explain what is the purpose of my code.

Comment: How about this - https://plnkr.co/edit/8C9lLLdCvvzFinaOXqtd?p=preview (note that you can expand myObj to contain as many keys as you like)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to bind to `INPUT`..

So it seems ,what you have is , a list of objects where the no. of elements in the list can vary.. and you want to bind all of them to `<input>`

If so then this would do the job:

```
<div ng-init="tempName = key" ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj">
    <label for="{{key}}" >{{key.toUpperCase()}}</label>
    <input name="{{key}}" id="{{key}}" type="text" ng-model="myObj[tempName]" />
</div>
```

here's an awesome [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hV1uODB0MzxpNQtFW5r9) doing just that

**EDIT:**

To ignore the empty fields : [use this](https://plnkr.co/edit/hV1uODB0MzxpNQtFW5r9?p=preview)

Comment: No. I don't need to bind all of them.  I need to bind last not empty field of the object to `INPUT`.

Comment: so you want to ignore empty fields ??

Comment: Empty. And non empty too. I need to bind to ONE `input` ONE `variable`.  Look at my code https://plnkr.co/edit/9vzVxNtgDd3aAeWzKtml?p=preview

Comment: okay 1. so you want to bind the one which is before the empty field, and only one, 2. also what if there are more then one empty fields ? what do you do then

Comment: `But if id-k is not empty all id-n where n < k is not empty too.`.  So I am always have: `n1, n2, n3, .... , n-k , <empty>, <empty> ....`.  And I need to bind `n-k`.  It is possible to have many empty field. But I have only one `last field before empty fields`.

Comment: I have updated my question to explain what is the purpose of my code.

Comment: Yeah so according to the above `$scope.myObj` out of all the id's you want to show/bind till id2(that is both id1 and id2) or only id2(that is the field before empty obj -> id1)

Comment: so i updated the plunkr, tell me if this is what you want and then ill add it to ans [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hV1uODB0MzxpNQtFW5r9?p=preview)